# Using SwiftUI or UIKit to position view elements?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui

This is more or less a repost of a question that I think could have been reproduced more minimally. I'm trying to form a text bubble using the triangle created by the overriden draw() function and the rest of the callout. I removed all the code that couldn't possibly affect the positioning of either the triangle or the box.

Recap: I'd like to move the triangle created by the draw function outside of the frame created in the initialization (Currently, it's inside the frame).

If I can add anything to clarify or make this question better, let me know.

```
class CustomCalloutView: UIView, MGLCalloutView {

    let dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
    let isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
    let tipHeight: CGFloat = 10.0
    let tipWidth: CGFloat = 20.0
    lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView()
    lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView()

    weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

    //MARK: Subviews -



    required init() {
        // init with 75% of width and 120px tall
        super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 
        UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75, height: 120)))

        setup()
    }

    override var center: CGPoint {
        set {
            var newCenter = newValue
            newCenter.y -= bounds.midY
            super.center = newCenter
        }
        get {
            return super.center
        }
    }

    func setup() {
        // setup this view's properties
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}


func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, 
animated: Bool) {
    //Always, Slightly above center
    self.center = view.center.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height))
    view.addSubview(self)

}


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    // Draw the pointed tip at the bottom.
    let fillColor: UIColor = .black

    let tipLeft = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0) - (tipWidth / 2.0)
    let tipBottom = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0), y: rect.origin.y + 
    rect.size.height)
    let heightWithoutTip = rect.size.height - tipHeight - 1

    let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    let tipPath = CGMutablePath()
    tipPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft, y: heightWithoutTip))
    tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipBottom.x, y: tipBottom.y))
    tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft + tipWidth, y: heightWithoutTip))
    tipPath.closeSubpath()

    fillColor.setFill()
    currentContext.addPath(tipPath)
    currentContext.fillPath()
}
}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, I'll edit the post now. I'd like to move the triangle created by the draw function outside of the frame created in the initialization (Currently, it's inside the frame).